# Sentence in mysql for java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I guess that the error is in sentenciaSQL, but i don't know how to fix it =

```
public long guardar(PedidoDTO obj) throws SQLException {

PedidoDTO dto = new PedidoDTO();
String url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/capacitacion?user=capacitacion&password=password";

try {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    String sentenciaSQL = "INSERT INTO capacitacion.pedido (id, fecha, total, folio) VALUES(NULL,'" +  obj.getId() + "," +  obj.getFecha() + ","+ obj.getTotal() + "," + obj.getFolio() + "')";
        PreparedStatement s =  con.prepareStatement(sentenciaSQL);
        s.executeUpdate();
        for(PedidoDetalleDTO detalle:obj.getPedidoDetalle()){
            dto.getId();
            dto.getFecha();
            dto.getTotal();
            dto.getFolio();
        }con.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
return dto.getId();
}
```

Comment: ... error? It's a good idea to the error as well.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace and/or the error message you get. Otherwise, we'll be only able to guess whats the problem.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should wrap the code after creating the connection in a `try...finally` structure, putting the `con.close()` statement into the `finally` block.  Otherwise, it is possible that an exception will be thrown before you close the connection (i.e., the connection will become a dangling resource).

Comment: The stacktrace is not needed if you read the code. Also, you people will notice that the error is not just in the wrong SQL usage, the main problem is what OP needs to achieve and his/her lack of knowledge to do it.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a good usage for the PreparedStatement, it should be like this:

```
String sentenciaSQL = "INSERT INTO capacitacion.pedido (id, fecha, total, folio) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement s =  con.prepareStatement(sentenciaSQL);
s.setInt(1, obj.getId());
s.setDate(2, obj.getFecha());
s.setDouble(3, obj.getTotal());
s.setString(4, obj.getFolio());
```

By the way, why are you using this block code:

```
for(PedidoDetalleDTO detalle:obj.getPedidoDetalle()){
    dto.getId();
    dto.getFecha();
    dto.getTotal();
    dto.getFolio();
}
```

It looks like you want to add the order details (detalles de la orden/pedido) in the table using the same method, but is not going to work in this way. It would be good if you post your functional requirement to help you solve your real problem.

Comment: Good answer Luiggi!  Looks like you finished typing 2 minutes before I did.

Comment: Wow u are awesome dude, now the problem that i have it's this: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). I don't know if it has something to do that i have "id" with an auto-incremente on my data base? How can i fix it?

Comment: @user1617806 based in your new [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12100246/1065197), your code is still wrong and you haven't followed the corrections posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely.  The error you've made is that your first and last variables in sentenciaSQL each have lone, unclosed tick marks (on ID and folio):

```
VALUES(NULL,'" +  obj.getId()
```

and...

```
obj.getFolio() + "')";
```

Since you're already using a prepared statement, the best way to go about this, is to add your values as parameters, like this:

```
String sentenciaSQL = "INSERT INTO capacitacion.pedido (id, fecha, total, folio) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement s =  con.prepareStatement(sentenciaSQL);
s.setInt(1,obj.getId());
s.setDate(2,obj.getFecha());
s.setInt(3,obj.getTotal());
s.setString(4,obj.getFolio().toString());
s.execute();
```

Note, that I have made assumptions that your Id and Total are integers.  You will want to substitute with the actual data types.

Also, if you don't care about how many rows have been updated, you can use execute() instead of executeUpdate().  Either one is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert five pieces of data into four fields.  Your query will try to insert `NULL` into `id`, `obj.getId()` into `fecha`, etc.  It looks like removing the `NULL` in your values list would be a good first step.

Comment: but if i had like auto:increment in "id" on my data base I need to put the sintax or i don't mentioned?, because now im doing in it like this, but even thoug still not working =( String sentenciaSQL = 
  "INSERT INTO capacitacion .pedido VALUES(" + obj.getFecha()
  + ", " + obj.getFolio() + ")";
    
   Statement s =  con.createStatement();
   s.executeUpdate(sentenciaSQL);
   for(PedidoDetalleDTO detalle:obj.getPedidoDetalle()){
    dto.getId();
    dto.getFecha();
    dto.getFolio();

Comment: now i put it like im gonna show you, but the problem stills, what could it be?

Comment: String sentenciaSQL = 
  "INSERT INTO capacitacion .pedido (fecha, folio) VALUES (" 
   + obj.getFecha() + ", " + obj.getTotal() + ", " + obj.getFolio() + ")";

Comment: Sorry i already put this (fecha, total, folio) and stills having a problem i don't know if it has something to do the auto_increment of my database?

Comment: Sorry, I had to run AFK.  Take a look at BryceAtNetwork23's solution.  It's more explicit than string interpolation, which is good on many levels (performance, readability, maintainability, etc.).