# Java lists connected to a database out of parameters?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

This is the code of my data base that its giving this error `java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range 1 > number of parameters`, which is 0

And I'm going to put the code of what I need to save on my database:

```
PedidoDTO nuevoPedido = new PedidoDTO();
nuevoPedido.setFolio("323423"); 
nuevoPedido.setFecha(new Date());
nuevoPedido.addDetalle(detalle1); 
nuevoPedido.addDetalle(detalle2); 
nuevoPedido.addDetalle(detalle3);  
long pedidoId =dao.guardar(nuevoPedido); 
System.out.println( "ID del nuevo pedido: " + pedidoId );

public long guardar(PedidoDTO obj) throws SQLException {

    PedidoDTO dto = new PedidoDTO();
    String url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/capacitacion?user=capacitacion&password=password";

    try {
        System.out.println("Hola");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        String sentenciaSQL = 
        "INSERT INTO capacitacion .pedido (fecha, total, folio) VALUES (" 
            + obj.getFecha() + ", " + obj.getTotal() + ", " + obj.getFolio() + ")";
            PreparedStatement s =  con.prepareStatement(sentenciaSQL);
            //s.setInt(1, obj.getId()); 
            s.setLong(1, obj.getFecha()); 
            s.setDouble(2, obj.getTotal()); 
            s.setString(3, obj.getFolio()); 
            s.execute(); 
            for(PedidoDetalleDTO detalle:obj.getPedidoDetalle()){
                dto.getId();
                dto.getFecha();
                dto.getTotal();
                dto.getFolio();
            }con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return dto.getId();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
VALUES (" 
            + obj.getFecha() + ", " + obj.getTotal() + ", " + obj.getFolio() + ")
```

should be

```
VALUES (?,?,?)
```

When you use preparedstatement, you will set values using `s.set...(..)`

Read this tutorial on how to use [preparedstatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
 "INSERT INTO capacitacion .pedido (fecha, total, folio) VALUES (" 
        + obj.getFecha() + ", " + obj.getTotal() + ", " + obj.getFolio() + ")";
```

with this:

```
 "INSERT INTO capacitacion .pedido (fecha, total, folio) VALUES (? , ? , ? )";
```

This is the way to build a parameterized Prepared statement. ? is a placeholder for your paremeters.